# Google Map in multipage form.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, geocoding

I have a `multipage` form. The different pages are divided by fieldsets, and you can navigate between them using buttons. On the second fieldset, e.g the second "page", I'd like to have a map, and a search field where you can type in your address.

The problem is that the map won't show on the second "page". If I put the map outside of the form, it shows and works as intended.

I use the [HPNeo Gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html) for the map.

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
 <h2 class="fs-title">Foo</h2>
 <textarea id="" name="" placeholder="" rows="4" cols="50" class=""></textarea>
 <input id="" type="" name="" placeholder="" class="" />
 <textarea id="" name="" class=""></textarea>
 <input id="" type="" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
 <!--Page 2-->
<fieldset>
   <h2 class="fs-title">Bar</h2>
   <label for="address">Address:</label>
   <div class="input">
   <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
   <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
   </div>
   <div id="mapcontainer"></div>
  </fieldset>
```

**JS:**

```
 var map;
 $(document).ready(function () {
        map = new GMaps({
            div: '#mapcontainer',
            lat: -12.043333,
            lng: -77.028333
        });
        $('geocoding_form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            GMaps.geocode({
                address: $('#address').val().trim(),
                callback: function (results, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {
                        var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                        map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
                        map.addMarker({
                            lat: latlng.lat(),
                            lng: latlng.lng()
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: It seems a size problem. Try giving sizes manually for `#mapcontainer`. And if you know using browser's console, check sizes of `#mapcontainer` in two cases.

Comment: Probably your #mapcontainer has no dimensions when you create the map, as it is not displayed. Try creating the map when the second page is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said this is likely a sizing problem in that, when the map is initialized, the map container has a width and height of 0, since it is hidden. You should be able to get round this by either waiting to initialize your map until the second 'page' is shown (I assume you have some JavaScript somewhere that shows/hides, so you can just attach it that) or another alternative is to fire the maps resize event when it is shown.

For a project I was doing I had a similar problem, except that map was initially hidden in a Bootstrap modal dialog. With this I also had the problem that every time the map was hidden and shown again after being initialized the map would go screwy. Again this was due to the fact that when the map was hidden again the map containers height and width was 0 again.

To get round this I added a 'data-attribute' to my map container called `data-maps-initialized`, initially set to false. When the modal with the map in was shown I fired the Google Maps initialization and set this attribute to true. When it was hidden and shown again I checked this attribute, and if it was true I triggered the Resize event instead. Here's the code I used

```
var map;
$('#mapsModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    //if map is not initialized
    if ($('#gMapsContainer').attr('data-maps-initialized') === 'false') {
        initialize();
        $('#gMapsContainer').attr('data-maps-initialized', 'true');
    } else {
        //fire resize event
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    }
});
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.74, -2.3),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gMapsContainer"),
        mapOptions);
}
```

The `$('#mapsModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {...` line is my listener for when the modal is shown/hidden, so in your case this would just be whatever you have set up that shows/hides your pages.

Please note I am not saying this is the best way in the world of doing things, but it worked for me with my problem and yours sounds similar!